# Using a for loop to replace if statement

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to use a for loop to cycle though an array and test for two conditions. I've done it with a foreach loop, but trying to get it done with a for loop. Below is the if block and for loop that I've been working on.

```
        if (empty($scores[0]) ||
        empty($scores[1]) ||
        empty($scores[2]) ||
        !is_numeric($scores[0]) ||
        !is_numeric($scores[1]) ||
        !is_numeric($scores[2])) {
            $scores_string = 'You must enter three valid numbers for scores.';
            break;
    }
```

Here is the HTML and PHP.

HTML:

```
<form action="." method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="process_scores" />

    <label>Choose action:</label><br />
    <input class="radio" type="radio" name="calculate" value="average" checked="checked">Average<br />
    <input class="radio" type="radio" name="calculate" value="total">Total<br />
    <input class="radio" type="radio" name="calculate" value="both">Both<br />

    <label>Score 1:</label>
    <input type="text" name="scores[]"
           value="<?php echo $scores[0]; ?>"/><br />

    <label>Score 2:</label>
    <input type="text" name="scores[]"
           value="<?php echo $scores[1]; ?>"/><br />

    <label>Score 3:</label>
    <input type="text" name="scores[]"
           value="<?php echo $scores[2]; ?>"/><br />

    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Process Scores" /><br />

    <label>Scores:</label>
    <span><?php echo $scores_string; ?></span><br />

    <label>Score Total:</label>
    <span><?php echo $score_total; ?></span><br />

    <label>Average Score:</label>
    <span><?php echo $score_average; ?></span><br />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
$action =  $_POST['action'];
} else {
$action =  'start_app';
}

switch ($action) {
case 'start_app':
    $scores = array();
    $scores[0] = 70;
    $scores[1] = 80;
    $scores[2] = 90;
    break;
case 'process_scores':
    $scores = $_POST['scores'];


    // validate the scores
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($scores); $i++) {
        if (empty($scores[$i]) || !is_numeric($scores[$i])) {
        $scores_string = 'You must enter three valid numbers for scores.';
        break;
        }
    }


    // process the scores
    $scores_string = '';
    foreach ($scores as $s) {
        $scores_string .= $s . '|';
    }
    $scores_string = substr($scores_string, 0, strlen($scores_string)-1);

    // Radio buttons
    $calculate_type = $_POST['calculate'];

    switch ($calculate_type) {
        case 'average':
            $score_tally = $scores[0] + $scores[1] + $scores[2];
            $score_average = $score_tally / count($scores);
            $score_average = number_format($score_average, 2);
            break;
        case 'total':
            $score_total = $scores[0] + $scores[1] + $scores[2];
            $score_total = number_format($score_total, 2);              
            break;
        case 'both':
            $score_tally = $scores[0] + $scores[1] + $scores[2];
            $score_average = $score_tally / count($scores);
            $score_total = $scores[0] + $scores[1] + $scores[2];
            $score_total = number_format($score_total, 2);
            $score_average = number_format($score_average, 2);
            break;
    }

    break;
case 'process_rolls':
    $number_to_roll = $_POST['number_to_roll'];

    $total = 0;
    // $count = 0;
    $max_rolls = -INF;

    for ($count = 0; $count < 1000; $count++) {
        $rolls = 1;
        while (mt_rand(1, 6) != 6) {
            $rolls++;
        }
        $total += $rolls;
        $max_rolls = max($rolls, $max_rolls);
    }
    $average_rolls = $total / $count;

    break;


}
```

With this for loop under validate the scores in place, I yield no results when there is invalid data.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/array-reduce), since that's basically what you're doing: Reducing an array to a boolean.

```
if( array_reduce(
   $scores,
   function($a,$b) {return $a || empty($b) || !is_numeric($b);},
   false)) {
       $scores_string = "You must enter three valid numbers for scores.";
}
```

Comment: "{return $a || empty($b) || !is_numeric($b);}" how does that work?

Comment: `array_reduce()` will iterate all elements. `$a` is a copy of the cumulative result from previous iterations (an internal variable in `array_reduce()`). The function parameter is supposed to update it for the current iteration (`$b` is the current element) and return the new, updated value.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for a `for` loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($scores); $i++)
    if (empty($scores[$i]) || !is_numeric($scores[$i])) {
        $scores_string = 'You must enter three valid numbers for scores.';
        break;
    }
```

Comment: I've tried your example and I get nothing. The scores are being populated by user input. All text fields share the same name attribute "scores[]". I used $scores = $_POST['scores'] to obtain the user entries. As of now with your example in place, I get no error message indicating an empty or invalid number.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You mean you get no error message where _you should_? Or that you get _no output using correct data_? If it's the former, please check the condition inside `if`. If it's the latter, then yes, that's supposed to be working.

Comment: Correct! I should receive the $scores_string when the input field is blank or isNAN. Using the if block I posted above works fine, so I know there isn't a problem with the $scores_string.

Comment: You actually _do receive it_. You just make it '' (ie an _empty string_) right after the loop, using `$scores_string = '';`,so that setting it to the error message becomes useless...

Comment: You're welcome. Oh, and if my answer helped you solve your problem, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you testing if score is emtpy. If score is empty then `is_numeric` return false.

My version of `for` loop:

```php
for ($i = 0, $len = count($scores); $i < $len and is_numeric($scores[$i]); $i++) {}
if ($i !== $len) echo 'You must enter three valid numbers for scores.';
```

edit:
If you need to test if there are exactly 3 numeric items in array (as @geomagas suggest) then:

```php
for ($i = 0; $i < 3 and is_numeric($scores[$i]); $i++) {}

// If $i is less then 3 it's mean that one of items are not set or it's not numeric
if ($i < 3) echo 'You must enter three valid numbers for scores.';
```

edit:
Third solution which handle situation when array is not properly indexed. I'm posting this just for fun, refusing to use `empty` function which @geomagas forcing on me ;)

```php
$scores = array('234', '52', '245');

for (reset($scores); $valid = is_numeric(current($scores)) and next($scores);) {}

if ( ! $valid) echo 'You must enter three valid number for scores.';
```

Comment: Please see my comment to abstr's answer, I think it applies to yours as well.

Comment: No, no, I didn't mean that. I was thinking towards the possibility of _replacing_ `empty()` with `isset()` rather than eliminating it. What if `$scores` looks like this: `Array([0]=>4,[2]=>9)`? _NOTE: I still think this is not relevant to the question_.

Comment: If it will be `Array([0]=>4,[2]=>9)` then `$i` from my second example will be equal 2 and validation error will be shown. `isset/empty` it not necessary here.

Comment: No it wouldn't. Take a step back and think. _Would execution get past your `for` loop?_ Or would php bail out spitting an error? Did you even _try_ your own suggestion?

Comment: I assume that array is properly indexed and there is no missing "1" index. Otherwise I suggest to use `foreach` with `if` statement.

Comment: IMHO, you assume wrong. I think it's safer to assume that the OP added a `empty()` check (falsely!) to prevent situations like this. But that's just me. Other than that, I find nothing wrong with your answer, and I respect your effort to help.

Comment: Just for fun I posted third solution. I think it solves all problems :)

Comment: Ooops! sorry... Comment withdrawn!

Answer (score 0):

`empty()` should not be used since `0` is considered to be empty as well as is numeric.

```
$size = count($scores);
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    if (!is_numeric($scores[$i])) {
        $scores_string = 'You must enter three valid numbers for scores.';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost a good point, although that wasn't part of the question. But does `is_numeric` test if a variable is set?

Comment: `$scores[$i]` is always set, since the for loop counted the array size prior to usage.

Comment: Playing the _devil's advocate_, suppose `$scores` is `Array([0]=>4,[2]=>9,[5]=>12)`. _See also: Comments on ofca's answer_

Comment: hmm.. then `$scores = array_values($scores)` will do it. But @geomagas aren't we hijacking @user1890525's question? :)

Comment: +1: Yes you're right. In both your points. From my side, for all it's worth, I consider the answer improved (by you, I mean). Thank you for responding to my argument.

Comment: @geomagas You're welcome. SO needs more great question(er)s. You made good points.

Comment: [Dubito ergo cogito; cogito ergo sum](http://thinkexist.com/quotation/dubito-ergo-cogito-cogito-ergo-sum-i-doubt/347860.html)